# Android SQLite shows only one row

Tags: android, android-sqlite

This is my code to show the product on the list view in fragment.
here is my list view fragment, it shows only one item I cant figure it out the error please help me to fix it

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
    HashMap<String, String> recent = db.getRecentDetails();

    hidePDialog();

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setID(recent.get("pid"));
    product.setTitle(recent.get("pname"));
    product.setThumbnailUrl(recent.get("pimage"));
    product.setDes1(recent.get("pdesc1"));
    product.setDes2(recent.get("pdesc2"));


    // adding product to movies array
    productList.add(product);
```

this is my database helper part

```
 public HashMap<String, String> getRecentDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> recent = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECENT;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        recent.put("pname", cursor.getString(1));
        recent.put("pimage", cursor.getString(2));
        recent.put("pdesc1", cursor.getString(3));
        recent.put("pdesc2", cursor.getString(4));
        recent.put("pid", cursor.getString(5));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching address from Sqlite: " + recent.toString());

    return recent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the cursor, in your code you are just fetching one line. Do it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
    recent.put("pname", cursor.getString(1));
    recent.put("pimage", cursor.getString(2));
    recent.put("pdesc1", cursor.getString(3));
    recent.put("pdesc2", cursor.getString(4));
    recent.put("pid", cursor.getString(5));
    cursor.moveToNext();    
}
```

And you are just creating one `product`. I don´t know what your are trying, but your code don´t look like you are generating multiple entries. With a `HashMap`, you need also to put unique keys. Even if you have multiple entries in your database, the `HashMap` is only filled once and the next line will overwrite the existing entries.
If you really need a `HashMap`, use different keys or use an `ArrayList` with a `HashMap` as type. For example:

```
<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>
```

Or inside the loop where you fill the HashMap, you can manipulate the key:

```
recent.put("pname"+i, cursor.getString(1));
```

See the API for `HashMap.put()`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29

### EDIT

You can do it like this:

```
 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getRecentDetails() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> hashHolder = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECENT;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> recent = new HashMap<String, String>();
        recent.put("pname", cursor.getString(1));
        recent.put("pimage", cursor.getString(2));
        recent.put("pdesc1", cursor.getString(3));
        recent.put("pdesc2", cursor.getString(4));
        recent.put("pid", cursor.getString(5));
        hashHolder.add(recent);
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching address from Sqlite: " + recent.toString());
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user


    return hashHolder;
}
```

And get the data:

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashHolder= db.getRecentDetails();

    hidePDialog();
for(int i=0;i<hashHolder.size();i++){
    HashMap<String,String> recent = hashHolder.get(i);
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setID(recent.get("pid"));
    product.setTitle(recent.get("pname"));
    product.setThumbnailUrl(recent.get("pimage"));
    product.setDes1(recent.get("pdesc1"));
    product.setDes2(recent.get("pdesc2"));


    // adding product to movies array
    productList.add(product);
}
```

Sorry, that I cannot guarantee that there is not any mistake in my example, made it from scratch and cannot test it currently.

Comment: Sorry, had a little mistake here. Put the new HashMap inside the for loop. I edited the post...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be fetching only one row.
You are moving to first and getting the data from that row only.

You need to loop over the others with `moveToNext()` until all the rows are read.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html